# JavaScript OnLoad and SharePoint does not work

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I have tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc()
    {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetSuppliers, "Directory.js");
    };
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myfunc");
</script>
```

As suggest on another thread but this does not work.
If I use a link and specify `javascript:functionname();` then it works.

Anyone have any ideas?

- Matt

Comment: looks like correct code. But what is the context? What page?

Comment: Just a standard Web Part Page

Comment: Even added the code as a script in a Content Editor Web part and it is still not firing

Comment: OK after debugging it seems there is a problem with my javascript, myContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current() seems to be undefined yet when I click the link it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

The issue you are facing is that the `sp.js` (which holds the functions for the JavaScript Client Object Model) is not getting loaded before you call your function. It works when you click the link because the file is loaded before you click the link. We need to ensure that `sp.js` is loaded before you call `GetSuppliers`.

For that, we need to create a script dependency of the `Directory.js` on the `sp.js`.
The [RegisterSodDep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410388.aspx) will ensure that `sp.js` will be loaded before `Directory.js`.

Try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc()
    { 
        RegisterSodDep("Directory.js","sp.js");
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetSuppliers, "Directory.js");
    };
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myfunc");
</script>
```